# Twilio - On Premise Implementation

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am looking for help on Twilio.
Has twilio been implemented On Prem? Is this possible?
We have confidential data for users that needs to be shared on a call / sms. In the SaaS based instance the details are stored in the logs. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio cannot be implemented on-prem.